# Django: Tree stored in DB, derive JSON

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like so:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Node, null=True)
```

Let us assume I have the following tree stored using this DB structure:

[Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAhfP.png)

What is the most efficient way to obtain a JSON in the following structure, in a query written in Django's ORM?

```
{"node": "A", "children": [
    {"node": "B2", "children": [
        {"node": "C1", "children": []}, 
        {"node": "C2", "children": []}
    ]}, 
    {"node": "B1", "children": []}
]}
```

EDIT:

I do not want to use django-mptt or similar packages. I do not want to use JSON fields either. My question is around how one would write a query for this use case, and what the most efficient query would be.

Comment: You want to generate a tree of *all* `Node` records?

Comment: I suggest you to use https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield Package. It will store your data in JsonField

Comment: @ParthModi: but then querying on the elements, etc. might be more difficult (for example obtain all children of a given node). Typically one uses a JSON field, if you the structure is "free" and if you do not need to look inside the JSON a lot (except for PostgreSQL, for most backends, a JSON field is in fact just a `CharField`).

Comment: The `Node` model probably also has a `name`? or other attributes?

Comment: Yeah, to retrieve the data might get difficult. Other than that One onother package is django-mptt. It has many buil in retrieval features

Comment: if you are working with tree structure - the simplest way is to use `django-mptt` library - https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#the-problem

Comment: what do u mean in your edit? Django ORM does not return JSON, but QuerySets.